# Does critical strike multiply the damage from items or only base damage?

Tags: dota-2

Does a critical strike multiply the whole player damage (including +damage from items) or only the base damage from stats ?

*e.g.* My hero has a base damage of 100 and a monkey king bar that gives +88 damage. Normally I will hit for 188 damage, if I proc a 200% critical strike damage, will I do `(100*2)+88 = 288 dmg` or `(100+88)*2 = 376dmg` ?

**Bonus question** : will the bash damage from the MKB be multiplied by the critical stike ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Critical_strike):

> Because critical strike multiplies the attack damage of a unit, after attack damage modifiers, it is a scaling ability (unlike the damage of Monkey King Bar's mini-bash ability).

Since it is mentioned that it is a scaling ability, it can safely be concluded that critical strikes multiply the whole player damage, including +damage from items and attack modifiers.

> Bashes and Critical Strikes can proc on the same attack, and are never multiplied.

As seen from the above, both Bash and Critical Strike can proc on one hit, but the damage from Bash will not critically hit and is counted as additional source of damage.

Comment: I had read that section, but it wasn't 100% clear to me what `after attack damage modifiers` meant. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: "Enhanced damage" buffs like Tiny's Grow, Earthshaker's Enchant Totem and the double damage rune are the ones that only increase base damage from stats, for reference. If I recall correctly, skills like Brew's Drunken Brawler and Bounty Hunter's Jinada are still technically "crits" even though they are guaranteed on a cooldown, so they multiply damage from items like normal crits.